# Win10 iot and xampp

Tags: windows-iot, arm

I want to know if im able to install xampp on a raspberry pi3 b+ with win 10 ion on it.

I can't find any answer for this.

Comment: I don't believe so, but I think you would be better off installing Raspbian and a standard LAMP stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot install XAMPP on Windows 10 IoT Core, because

- XAMPP is compiled for Intel/AMD (x86) CPUs. The Raspberry Pi has an ARM CPU which is completely incompatible.
- Windows 10 IoT Core is a minimal version of Windows, lots of stuff is missing. This includes the Desktop (explorer.exe, dwm.exe), support for Windows Forms etc. This means even a recompiled version of XAMPP might fail to run.